# What does the Time (0040,A122) tag mean in DICOM header?

Tags: tags, dicom

I have some trouble understanding the value of `Time (0040,A122)` tag. I am trying to update an anonymization software, but I can't seem to find any example of the actual tag.

The [DICOM standard (PS 3.3)](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.14.html#para_a4263653-e18c-44b6-88fb-aab230ba1dd8) mentions that:

> This is the Value component of a Name/Value pair when the Concept implied by Concept Name Code Sequence (0040,A043) is a time.
>
> Note
>   The purpose or role of the date value could be specified in Concept Name Code Sequence (0040,A043).
>
> Required if the value that Concept Name Code Sequence (0040,A043) requires (implies) is a time. Shall not be present otherwise.

So basically `Concept Name Code Sequence (0040,A043)` specifies what type of time it is? I would like to know what are some examples of `Concept Name Code Sequence`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at the SR sample given from the DICOM standard section PS 3.20:

- [A.7.2 Target DICOM SR "Measurement Report" (TID 1500)](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part21/sect_A.7.2.html)

In particular:

```
>>>>1.5.1.1.4: HAS ACQ CONTEXT: TIME: (111061,DCM,"Study Time")  = "070844"
```

You may also want to check PS 3.16 for the definition of TID 1500:

- [TID 1500 Measurement Report](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part16/chapter_A.html#sect_TID_1500)

Just as a reminder, Enhanced SR are defined in PS 3.3:

- [A.35.2 Enhanced SR IOD](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.35.2.html)